# How to recover your google account contacts

Tags: contacts, google-account, data-recovery

I merged my contacts with Google. Later, I accidentally removed my Google account by removing it from contacts the options. There aren't any contacts visible to me now. Is there a way I can get my contacts back?

Comment: If you just hid your Google contacts, revert what you did. If you removed your Google account, add it again.

Comment: I did add it again. But that isn't hepling. Still no contacts visible. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try remove your account at the accounts and synchronisation panel in the settings and add it again so it will sync your full account.

Answer (score 0):

Also check you haven't deleted them fully from source.  If you have then google instructions on restoring contacts.  Google backs them up on  restore points and this can be done for up to a month after deleting